# How can I display fps count in STALKER:SoC?

Tags: stalker-shadow-of-chernobyl

I already found the console and tried things like `fps 1`, `show_fps`, `/fps` and `/fps on`, but nothing worked yet. I guess there is some command to display how many fps I have but **how** is it named?

I use no mods or something.

Comment: Does "rs_stats 1" work? (With no quotes)

Comment: O_O That fills up the left side of the screen really much (distractting) any other possibilities?

Comment: Outside of using a separate program like [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/) or a mod, I don't think there is a command that displays just FPS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The console command you need is

> rs_stats [on,off] - Toggles display of game engine statistics, including FPS.

There does not appear to be a command that will display just FPS, but you could potentially use [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/).

Source: [TweakGuide](http://www.tweakguides.com/STALKER_8.html)